# What word means "like a machine" in the sense of "precise or disciplined"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means "like a machine"? By this, I don't mean "robotic", nor "mechanical"—that implies stiff and repetitive, and I'm thinking more along the lines of how one would behave and carry themself. I want a synonym for "machine-like" that can be used to describe someone who is precise, resolute, and stoic. For describing something like, say, an army.

Example sentence: "He was so  incredibly disciplined, many described him as [x]."

Comment: Not mechanical, that implies stiff and repetitive, thinking more along the lines of how one would behave and carry themself

Comment: Single word requests require a sample sentence so that it can be seen what part of speech is needed and how it will be used.

Comment: I think "mechanistic" is the word you are looking for. But we do have a rule that questioners seeking a word should provide a sample sentence, with a blank space where such word might be inserted.

Comment: Edited to include example sentence (not a great example, but best I could think of)

Comment: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/mechanistic.html

Comment: @Cplusplusplus You do need to give us a clearer example. If you want the word to imply a lack of humanity or an unthinking approach to complex problems, the noun "automaton" might apply, which adjectivally would become "automated". But for "precise, resolute, and stoic" then "rigorous" might be a more suitable word - though it is a step removed from "mechanistic". It really all depends on what you are trying to say.

Comment: *Systematic* could fit the bill. *Fastidious* works, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think methodical and self-disciplined both fit your meaning.

From the Collins online dictionary:

> [methodical](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/methodical):If you describe someone as methodical, you mean that they do things carefully, thoroughly, and in order.)
>
> [self-disciplined](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-disciplined): Someone who is self-disciplined has the ability to control themselves and to make themselves work hard or behave in a particular way without needing anyone else to tell them what to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about "phlegmatic"? It means "not easily excited" or "calm"  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phlegmatic